# Cannot retrieve bucket name in IBM Cloud object storage using python

Tags: python, boto3, ibm-cloud-storage

While retrieving the bucket name, it shows me this error.

`CLIENT ERROR: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Invalid Argument`

And another thing I want to know that COS_ENDPOINT is correct or not. Because it's also showing me the XML formatting error while retrieving.
Here is the code:

```
import ibm_boto3
from ibm_botocore.client import Config, ClientError

# Constants for IBM COS values
COS_ENDPOINT = "https://s3.eu-gb.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"
COS_API_KEY_ID = "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token"
SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID = "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::a/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx::serviceid:ServiceId-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"

# Create resource
cos = ibm_boto3.resource("s3",
    ibm_api_key_id=COS_API_KEY_ID,
    ibm_service_instance_id=SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID,
    ibm_auth_endpoint=COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
    config=Config(signature_version="oauth"),
    endpoint_url=COS_ENDPOINT
)

def get_buckets():
    print("Retrieving list of buckets")
    try:
        buckets = cos.buckets.all()
        for bucket in buckets:
            print("Bucket Name: {0}".format(bucket.name))
    except ClientError as be:
        print("CLIENT ERROR: {0}\n".format(be))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to retrieve list buckets: {0}".format(e))

get_buckets()
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't answer it's **DONE**

Answer (score 1):

```
import ibm_boto3
from ibm_botocore.client import Config, ClientError

# Constants for IBM COS values
COS_ENDPOINT = "https://s3.eu-gb.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"
COS_API_KEY_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token"
SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

"resource_instance_id": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/3c467ce9e6d84b90065fd00be3065964:65c5b3g2-7db5-4251-93a1-a7c33486d5e9::"

In Service instance ID use : 65c5b3g2-7db5-4251-93a1-a7c33486d5e9 (***This is not my resource_instance_id***)

```
# Create resource
cos = ibm_boto3.resource("s3",
    ibm_api_key_id=COS_API_KEY_ID,
    ibm_service_instance_id=SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID,
    ibm_auth_endpoint=COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
    config=Config(signature_version="oauth"),
    endpoint_url=COS_ENDPOINT
)

for bucket in cos.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```